# EnumProcesses - weird behaviour

Tags: c++, windows, shell, api

I have some weird behaviour while using WIndows API function EnumProcesses()

I have a function to determine wether a process with a certain name is already running which delivery different results wether I open the .executable manually (doubleclick) or open it via shell.

When I open it via shell it detects its running only 1 time (itself) and all is fine. When I open it using doubleclick on the .exe file however the function is returning true (already running) because the loop lists me the same process twice.

For the following code-snipped it is to mention that:

```
this->thisExecutableFile
```

contains argv[0] (initialised from running the program) to get the own process-name as you can see here:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ClientUpdate* update = ClientUpdate::getInstance();
    update->setThisExecutableFile(argv[0]);
    if (update->clientUpdateProcessIsRunning() == false) {
    ...
```

My goal is to find out if another instance of this process is already running and in this case exit it.

Here is my code:

```
bool ClientUpdate::clientUpdateProcessIsRunning()
{
    bool retVal = false;

    uint16_t processCount = 0;
    unsigned long aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    if(!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
        return false;

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(unsigned long);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++) {
        if (aProcesses[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, aProcesses[i]);
        wchar_t buffer[50];
        GetModuleBaseNameW(hProcess, 0, buffer, 50);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        std::wstring tempBuffer(buffer);
        std::string tempStringBuffer(tempBuffer.begin(), tempBuffer.end());
        boost::filesystem::path p(this->thisExecutableFile);
        if(_strcmpi(p.filename().string().c_str(), tempStringBuffer.c_str()) == 0) {
            processCount++;
            if(processCount > 1) {
                retVal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

I know that the base-path is different when using doubleclick on the file or calling it via shell. (shell produces only filename while doubleclick passes entire path + filename into argv[0]) but I fixed that issue using

```
boost::filesystem::path p(this->thisExecutableFile);
p.fileName()
```

Which returns the correct filename (without path) in both cases I checked using print.

I am pretty puzzled why EnumProcesses() returns me the same file twice when calling the file via doubleclick instead of shell. Its not spawning two processed and in taskmanager I dont see anything like this either.

Is this a bug or I need to know something about the method I couldnt find in docs?

Comment: There is another way of detecting and exiting if a 2nd process is run.  At application start create a Win32 Mutex with a unique name (a GUID for example) using `CreateMutex`.  If `CreateMutex` returns `NULL` with `GetLastError` returning ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS - then you are the 2nd process.

Comment: Oh that sounds cool. Sounds like something like exclusive lock on the executable. I try that!

Comment: @RichardCritten `CreateMutex` will not return NULL if the mutex already exists. It will return a handle to the existing mutex. In any case, a mutex will only tell you if an earlier instance is running. To actually exit the instance, you have to tell it to exit, either with a window message, or a packet sent to a named pipe, socket, or mailslot, or any number of other available IPC mechanisms

Comment: I suspect the original problem may have been the lack of error checking.  If one of the processes on the list had exited by the time you got to it, you'd wind up seeing the previous process name again because it was still sitting in the buffer.  (On the other hand, I'm not sure why this would happen consistently.)

Comment: @up hmm yes that is possible. Anyway I will not use EnumProcesses anymore to check if a process is already running. Maybe its not made for this kind of task anyway. The new solution works awesome and very stable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint by Richard Critten I was able to fix it. My method is much smaller now and easier. (Also probably also alot more performant then scanning entire process-stack.) :D

Here is the solution

```
bool ClientUpdate::clientUpdateProcessIsRunning()
{

    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutexA(NULL, TRUE, "client-updater-mtx");
    DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
    return dwErr == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `"client-updater-mtx"` is hardly unique. Pick a string representation of a GUID instead.

Comment: I just picked this string out of my mind and cannot imagine for it to be non-unique. But anyway for real I prepended the project name which I simply did not wanted to spoil here making it unique enough.

Comment: Uhm... what's wrong with a GUID? GUIDs were invented to be unique, you know?

Comment: I personally don't like GUIDs as the sole name, because that makes debugging harder (try to recognize a series of random characters). So I prefix the GUID with a human-readable name, e. g. "client-updater-mtx.{SOME-GUID-HERE}". Best of both worlds.